# Use a function from a component in another component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a delete button that is outside a component, but the delete method works only if it has google map in the component, can I call this function somehow in another component?

e.g

Component.Vue

```js
async function deletePoint() {
      await points.listPoint(route.params.adventureId, route.params.id)
        .then(async () => {
          await map.value.circles[points.singlePointDetails.sort].setOptions({ label: '', icon: '', opacity: 0, editable: false, clickable: false })
          await map.value.circles[points.singlePointDetails.sort].Circle.setOptions({ fillOpacity: 0, strokeOpacity: 0, editable: false, clickable: false })
          await map.value.circles[points.singlePointDetails.sort].setMap(null)
          await map.value.circles.splice(points.singlePointDetails.sort, 1)
        })

      await points.deletePoint(route.params.adventureId, route.params.id)

    }
```

I want to use this function above in another component, I can't just copy and paste, because the other component doesn't have access to google map.

Comment: If another component is the child of the compenent with `deletePoint()`, you can use `this.$emit`

Comment: @cafetayyar its child to parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say `childComponentA` is a child component of `parentComponentB`

**parentComponentB.vue**:

```
<childComponentA @deletePointEmit="deletePoint" />
```

and

**childComponentA.vue**:

Let's say there is a method `methodTriggerEmit()` that triggers the `this.$emit`.

```
methods: {
   methodTriggerEmit() {
      this.$emit('deletePointEmit');
   },
},
```

If you execute `methodTriggerEmit()` in `childComponentA`, it will execute the `deletePoint()` in `parentComponentB`.

If `router-view` is used, you can use this:
`<router-view @deletePointEmit="deletePoint"></router-view>`

Comment: The problem is, the parent has only router-view in it, and I think it's not possible to `<router-view @deletePointEmit="deletePoint" />`

Comment: Could you try this `<router-view @deletePointEmit="deletePoint"></router-view>`?